# not work class .numeric after add new input. what do i do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

why after add new input, class `.numeric` (normal number formatting) in js code not worked?

This way for `normal number formatting` is right?
What is your suggestion?
**i not want use of plugin.**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zgWr3/1/)**

```
$("input:text.numeric").keyup(function () {
    $val = $(this).val().match(/[0-9]/g).reverse().join("").match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g).join(",").match(/./g).reverse().join("");
    $(this).val($val)
})
```

With respect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`delegate()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method to bind the handler to the `.column` container.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/zgWr3/3/

```
$('.column').delegate("input.numeric:text",'keyup',function () {
    $val = $(this).val().match(/[0-9]/g).reverse().join("").match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g).join(",").match(/./g).reverse().join("");
    $(this).val($val)
});
```

This way, any `"input.numeric:text"` elements inside of `.column` will invoke the handler irrespective of when they're added to the DOM.

I also changed the selector around a little. Seems more understandable to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you add something to the page after it is done loading you will need to use the live() function on your scripts to make them work on the new data.

If you do something like:

```
$('#container').append('<div class="clickme">The text goes here</div>');
```

or

```
$('#container').load('script.php');
```

...they are both considered adding to the page.

---

Using live(), your code would become:

```
$("input:text.numeric").live('keyup', function () {
    $val = $(this).val().match(/[0-9]/g).reverse().join("").match(/[0-9]{1,3}/g).join(",").match(/./g).reverse().join("");
    $(this).val($val)
});
```

Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 1):

You need a future-proof event observer. Since the `keyup` bind is assigned to existing nodes, any nodes you create afterwards will not be bound to that event. You need to use `live` or `delegate`

Change

```
$("input:text.numeric").keyup(function () {
```

to

```
$("input:text.numeric").live('keyup',function () {
```

or

```
$('.find_input').delegate('input:text.numeric','keyup',function () {
```

`delegate()` is much more resource-friendly than `live()` but you need to know the parent ahead of time. In your example, I'd recommend it.

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/zgWr3/4/